# Mixture of log-logistic distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a random dataset that I'm fitting a log-logistic distribution to. I would then like to calculate limited expected values $\mathbb{E}[X \wedge x]$ for various $x$, where $X$ is distributed according to the fitted distribution. However, because the dataset is random, the value of $\mathbb{E}[X \wedge x]$ depends on the underlying dataset, and there's quite a bit of variation in the values. Therefore I would like to find a distribution that represents the "average" fit, and use that to calculate the "average" value of $\mathbb{E}[X \wedge x]$.

One way to obtain the average of $\mathbb{E}[X\wedge x]$ is to sample the random dataset many times, fit several log-logistic distributions, and average their limited expected values:
$$\text{average of } \mathbb{E}[X \wedge x] \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i \wedge x].$$
In this case, the "average" fit is given by a mixture of the fitted log-logistic distributions, each with weight $\frac{1}{n}$.

However, for practical purposes it would be much easier to have a single parametric distribution that describes the fit. Naively, I decided to try averaging the parameters of the fitted log-logistic distributions:
$$\bar{\alpha} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i; \bar{\beta} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i.$$
If $X$ is log-logistic with parameters $\bar{\alpha}$ and $\bar{\beta}$, I found that $\mathbb{E}[X\wedge x]$ is remarkably close to $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i \wedge x]$.

So, at least empirically, averaging the parameters of the fitted log-logistic distributions seems to approximate the mixture distribution fairly well. My question is whether there is any theoretical grounding for this. I wrote out the formula for the limited expected value of a log-logistic distribution, but I was not able to get any good approximations:
$$\mathbb{E}[X\wedge x] = \alpha \int_0^{\frac{(x/\alpha)^\beta}{1+(x/\alpha)^\beta}} t^{1/\beta} (1-t)^{-1/\beta} \ dt + x \left(1-\frac{(x/\alpha)^\beta}{1+(x/\alpha)^\beta}\right).$$
It might be useful to know that for my purposes $\beta$ is around $1.1$ and I'm primarily concerned with $x/\alpha$ in the range of about $1$ to $15$.

Comment: While I don't know the subject matter justify a theoretical grounding, do you not just have to evaluate an incomplete beta function? $\mathbb{E}[X \wedge x]=\alpha  B_{1-\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{\alpha }\right)^{\beta }+1}}\left(1+\frac{1}{\beta },1-\frac{1}{\beta }\right) + x \left(1-\frac{\left(\frac{x}{\alpha }\right)^{\beta }}{\left(\frac{x}{\alpha }\right)^{\beta }+1}\right)$.

Comment: @JimB Yes, that is correct, but I don't see how that helps me approximate the average limited expected value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being slow to understand.  You have a single sample from a log-logistic distribution.  You could obtain confidence intervals for $\mathbb{E}[X \wedge x]$ using the bootstrap approach you describe.  You could also use maximum likelihood to estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and then find confidence intervals for $\mathbb{E}[X \wedge x]$.  Where I'm confused is when you say "there's quite a bit of variation".  That begs the question:  do you have a sample from a log-logistic distribution or something else?  If the latter, then you'd need to describe how the extra variation is involved.

Comment: I am not sampling from a log-logistic distribution. I am fitting log-logistic distributions to several different datasets that vary slightly, but I want to understand the "average" fitted distribution. Estimating the average of $\mathbb{E}[X \wedge x]$ is not an issue. The issue is I want to describe the "average" fit by a single log-logistic distribution. So the question is - how do I determine the "best" parameters to describe the "average" fit?